# ГОСТ курсового проекта

Tags: гост, шрифты

Подскажите, пожалуйста ГОСТ для оформления текста (шрифт текста) программы в курсовом проекте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это ГОСТ тип А и Б - оформление текста для ПЗ и программы

Comment: да.

Comment: так по поисковику и ищи, первая ссылка выдаст тебе шрифты для скачивания. Осталось только подгрузить их в Word(если в нем работаешь). Не так давно сам писал курсовые и оформлял их по ГОСТам )))

Comment: Спасибо=) нашел! От уже эти курсовоые=) пристанут так пристанут)